# How to manually switch the session context in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, session-state

Is there a way to manually switch the ASP.Net session or an extensibility mechanism that allows you to provide a way plug in a cookie resolver that would pull out cookies that you create using Javascript?

Background
We are trying to integrate a Node UI with a ASP.NET MVC JSON services layer (not Web API) and take advantage of ASP.NETs distributed session support using SQL as the persistence store.

Comment: Rory, can you please provide me a link to what you are referring to? I looked through my threads and didn't see any anwsers that weren't the answer. I might not understand the site works though.

Comment: I figured it out Rory. I didn't realize I needed to click the check icon. Everything should be updated now. Thanks for the heads up.